# Altium: Cannot click to move a specific objects on a different layer

Tags: altium

I have a problem in Altium where I cannot move this specific component on different layers then the top layer. I attached an image below showing how the mouse goes into selection mode when holding the mouse button. It doesn't matter if I've selected the component before hand or not, it won't move it anyways.
When moving the component on the top layer it works fine.

Have I missed something when creating the footprint? Is it not enough with just a pad to move around? But why would it work on one layer and than no other..? It makes no sense.

Thank you for your time!

[image: Trying to click and drag the component]

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: Is the component locked or not ? Check the properties ...

Comment: Can you please pull up the properties box of that part and show it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you component is locked. This usually happen when you try to drag a locked component.
Check in the properties panel. If you also can't select the component, double click on it to select. Then click on the "lock" icon in the "properties" panel to ulock it, then, you should be able to move it